# Is it possible to use MapCSS with OSMDroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I'm making an android app that uses OSMDroid for it's map engine and I wanted to make a custom theme for it and read up on MapCSS instead of creating tiles.

I've been doing research to find out how to incorporate the two and haven't had much luck.. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Mapsforge? This performs customisable, client-side rendering of OSM data. OSM files are converted to a custom binary format using an Osmosis plugin and then can be styled via an XML style file.

http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge